# Getting 400 Bad Request error while trying to move Azure resources via Postman

Tags: postman, azure-rest-api, azure-ad-b2b

I am trying to move resources from one resource group to another via Postman.

I got the access token successfully by using below parameters:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id='myclientid'
&scope=https://management.azure.com/.default
&grant_type=client_credentials
&client_secret='appclientsecret'
```

I am using query like below:

```
POST
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/mysubscriptionid/resourceGroups/resourcegroupname/moveResources?api-version=2021-04-01
```

Request Body

```json
{  
"resources" : "/subscriptions/mysubscriptionid/resourceGroups/resourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keyvaultname",  
"targetResourceGroup" : "/subscriptions/mysubscriptionid/resourceGroups/targetresourcegroupname"  
}
```

But I got error like below:

> { "error": { "code": "UnsupportedMediaType",
> "message": "The content
> media type 'text/plain' is not supported. Only 'application/json' is
> supported."
> } }

After changing the type to JSON, I am getting another error like below:

> { "error": { "code": "InvalidRequestContent", "message": "The request
> content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Error converting
> value
> "/subscriptions/mysubscriptionid/resourceGroups/resourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keyvaultname"
> to type 'System.String[]'. Path 'resources', line 2, position 143.'."
> } }

Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and was able to move resources successfully like below:***

[image]

**Make sure your request body is something like below:**

```json
{
"resources" : ["/subscriptions/XXXXXXX/resourceGroups/Test/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/testkeyvault549","/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/Test/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/sristackdem01"],
"targetResourceGroup" : "/subscriptions/XXXXXXX/resourceGroups/Demo"
}
```

When I executed the same query, I got below **response**:

[image]

Please **note** that resources parameter expects list of resource IDs in [ ]. So, make sure to add them.

***When I missed giving [ ] as mentioned above, I got the same error as you like below:***

[image]

**Reference:**

[Validate Azure Resource Move with Postman - Apostolidis Cloud Corner](https://www.cloudcorner.gr/microsoft/azure/validate-azure-resource-move-with-postman/)